# How to use eloquent to return records based on table column and count of hasMany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using laravel 5.1. I have two models

```
articles
authors
```

I want to find articles that have been published or have more than two authors. What is the simplest way to do this in eloquent?

```
$pub_articles = Articles::where('published',1)->get(); //get articles that are published
```

My guess is something like

```
$articles = Articles::where('published',1)
               ->orWhere(Articles->authors::count(),'>',2);
```

In SQL it could possibly be done this way

```
select a.id, a.published from articles a inner join authors au on a.id = au.article_id where a.published = 1 group by a.id, a.published having count(*) > 2
```

Comment: You have a many to many relationship here since I am guessing an author can also publish more than one article.  Do you have a reference table set up (something called `articles_authors`)?

Comment: You are right. I have not considered that at the moment, I was trying to wrap my head around different portions of eloquent and querying tables with relationships.
This is from scratch to there is no articles_authors table at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `has` method?

```
Articles::has('authors', '>', 1)->where('published',1)->get();
```

Comment: Has() works great, I overlooked it in the documentation. Thanks. I changed the 'where' to 'orWhere'.   
Articles::has('authors', '>=', 2)->orWhere('published',1)->get();